# How can I send POST and GET data to a Perl CGI script via the command line?

Tags: perl, command-line, post, cgi, get

I am trying to send a get or a post through a command-line argument. That is test the script in the command line before I test through a browser (the server has issues). I tried searching online, and I suppose I was probably using incorrect terminology because I got nothing. I know this is possible because I saw someone do it. I just don't remember how it was done.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you using the standard CGI module?

For example, with the following program (notice `-debug` in the arguments to `use CGI`)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use CGI qw/ :standard -debug /;

print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n",
      map { $_ . " => " . param($_) . "\n" }
      param;
```

you feed it parameters on the command line:

```
$ ./prog.cgi foo=bar baz=quux
Content-type: text/plain

foo => bar
baz => quux
```

You can also do so via the standard input:

```
$ ./prog.cgi
(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input; press ^D or ^Z when done)
foo=bar
baz=quux
^D
Content-type: text/plain

foo => bar
baz => quux
```

Answer (score 22):

To test a CGI program from the command line, you fake the environment that the server creates for the program. CGI.pm has a special offline mode, but often I find it easier not to use because of the extra setup I need to do for everything else my programs typically expect.

Depending on the implementation of your script, this involves setting many environment variables, which you can do from a wrapper script that pretends to be the server:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 export HTTP_COOKIE=...
 export HTTP_HOST=test.example.com
 export HTTP_REFERER=...
 export HTTP_USER_AGENT=...
 export PATH_INFO=
 export QUERY_STRING=$(cat query_string);
 export REQUEST_METHOD=GET

 perl program.cgi
```

If you're doing this for a POST request, the environment is slightly different and you need to supply the POST data on standard input:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 export CONTENT_LENGTH=$(perl -e "print -s q/post_data/");
 export HTTP_COOKIE=...
 export HTTP_HOST=test.example.com
 export HTTP_REFERER=...
 export HTTP_USER_AGENT=...
 export PATH_INFO=...
 export QUERY_STRING=$(cat query_string);
 export REQUEST_METHOD=POST

 perl program.cgi < post_data
```

You can make this as fancy as you need and each time you want to test the program, you change up the data in the query_string or post_data files. If you don't want to do this in a shell script, it's just as easy to make a wrapper Perl script.

Answer (score 5):

Old discussion, but I was looking for the same answers - so for those who follow - this is what I found out

RTFM! from the CGI man page ( and there is more )
DEBUGGING
    If you are running the script from the command line or in the perl
    debugger, you can pass the script a list of keywords or parameter=value
    pairs on the command line or from standard input (you don't have to
    worry about tricking your script into reading from environment
    variables). You can pass keywords like this:

```
    your_script.pl keyword1 keyword2 keyword3

or this:

   your_script.pl keyword1+keyword2+keyword3

or this:

    your_script.pl name1=value1 name2=value2

or this:

    your_script.pl name1=value1&name2=value2

To turn off this feature, use the -no_debug pragma.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to alter the perl script, you can call it with at least two environment variables set, as others mentioned already. To simulate a GET request:

```
shell$ QUERY_STRING=limit=20 REQUEST_METHOD=GET ./events_html.pl
```

That's the console shortcut for www.myserver.org/events_html.pl?limit=20

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to do this from the command line, bypassing your server. This page explains all: [Perl CGI debugging (sitewizard.com)](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/servererror.shtml) (Especially item 6 on that page). Here I quote the most important part:

> To test the script offline using the
>   GET method, simply set the
>   QUERY_STRING environment variable
>   accordingly. If you are using Windows,
>   you might use the following command
>   line in a DOS window prior to running
>   the script in the same window:
>
> set QUERY_STRING=recipient=John@Doe.com&Fullname=M+Name
>
> To test the script offline using the
>   POST method, put the line below into a
>   text file named, say, testinput.txt.
>
> recipient=John@Doe.com&Fullname=M+Name
>
> Then redirect that file as an input to
>   the script. On Unix systems as well as
>   under Windows' MSDOS prompt, you can
>   do it this way:
>
> perl -w scriptname.pl < testinput.txt
>
> Your script will then receive that
>   input as though it was sent it by a
>   form on the website. Check the error
>   messages that perl spouts, if any, to
>   help you track the problem in the
>   script.

Comment: For reference, the environment-variable/standard input approach works with any CGI application, Perl or otherwise.

Comment: This advice is missing quite a bit, not to mention it's example command line has no hope of working.

Answer (score 1):

To give a cgi script post data:

```
$ echo -n 'a=b;c=d' | REQUEST_METHOD=POST CONTENT_LENGTH=999 perl index.cgi
```

To give a cgi script get data:

```
$ perl index.cgi 'a=b;c=d'
```

Answer (score -1):

[LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) comes with ready made scripts that can be used from the command-line. Check for `GET` and `POST` scripts in your system.

Comment: This is a different thing. He wants to run a CGI script from the command line (no server) to test it.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, you can use VBScript to write a command line util that calls into the MS XML library:

```
Dim XMLHttp : Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
On Error Resume Next

strIPAddress = WScript.Arguments(0)
strMACAddress = WScript.Arguments(1)
strSubnetMask = WScript.Arguments(2)

On Error Goto 0

WScript.Echo "Attempting to wake host " & strIPAddress & " on NIC " & strMACAddress &
"using netmask " & strSubnetMask

strGetUrl = http://wolService/WolService/WolService.asmx/WakeBroadcast?hostIP=" &
strIPAddress & "&macAddress=" & strMACAddress & "&subnetMask=" & strSubnetMask

XMLHttp.Open "GET", strGetUrl, False
XMLHttp.Send ""

WScript.Echo XMLHttp.ResponseText
```

Edit: This script sends HTTP requests and can be used from the command line. I got confused by the question 'How can I send POST and GET data to a Perl CGI script via the command line' and thought this was about sending POST and GET data to a Perl CGI script via the command line from an unspecified client OS.

Comment: He wants to run a script on the command line to test it. There is no server.