# How to test Perl CGI script for file upload from the command line?

Tags: perl, file, command-line, upload, cgi

I have a Perl script with a call `my $file_handle = $cgi->upload('uploaded_file')`. Is there a way to test this script from command line before deploying to the web server? I looked at ([How can I send POST and GET data to a Perl CGI script via the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224158/how-can-i-send-post-and-get-data-to-a-perl-cgi-script-via-the-command-line)) and other questions, but could not find any information for passing a file for upload from the command line. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please elaborate by providing the said script. What OS are you using, which command line? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use Perl to actually perform the upload? If not then the easiest thing to do is probably use `curl` - as in `curl -T file https://yoursite.com/your-script.cgi`.

Comment: @David that requires them to already run the program with a web server. They want to run the code without a web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file upload is just another POST request! See [DEBUGGING in CGI.pm](http://p3rl.org/CGI#DEBUGGING). The program is `index.pl`, the file to upload is `somefile.bin` and the form field name is `uploaded_file`:

```
REQUEST_METHOD=POST \
CONTENT_TYPE='multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY' \
perl index.pl < <(
    perl -MHTTP::Request::Common=POST -e'
        print POST(
            undef,
            Content_Type => "form-data",
            Content => [ uploaded_file => [ "somefile.bin" ]]
        )->content
    '
)
```

Comment: Can you explain the `< <(...)` please? Why is there a space?

Comment: `<()` is http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html (avoids temporary file or shell var) ; `<` redirects from file descriptor into the process stdin. Edit: just noticed, a simple pipe will also do.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you @daxim. I see Content_Type set to "form-data" in this POST method, but when I dump $cgi, I see:
'Content-Disposition' => 'form-data; name="uploaded_file"; filename="wrapper_sbs.bin"',
'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream'
If I change the uploaded file extension to ".sh", the Content-Type is becoming 'application/x-sh'. Is there any way to specify the Content-Type without regard to the file extension?

Comment: Sure, that's in the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Request::Common#POST-$url), scroll down to `Form-based File Upload`.